# Which OAuth2 grant type can I use for a LAN web app?

Tags: web-applications, oauth-2.0, auth0

I use auth0 as an authorization service and need to configure allowed callback URLs and allowed URLs for CORS, but there's all kinds of private subnets which wouldn't be known in advance and host IPs are dynamic anyway due to DHCP.

Is it more appropriate in this situation to use a device code instead of the usual authorization code grant type for web apps? or would the same issue be present?

Answer (score 1):

Connectivity tends to just require valid outbound internet connections from the client (browser / server / device) to the Authorization Server - this works fine from almost anywhere.

Callback urls are managed via browser redirects so will almost certainly work fine - no special setup needed.

There are some LAN scenarios where an Identity Provider url may only be reachable within the intranet - in which case the user + browser will also need to be in the intranet.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My scenario is the following: Client app is a web app hosted on a machine within a residential LAN. The machine has no screen or USB input so the user navigates to the web app through another device using the LAN IP of that machine. However I can't configure arbitrary IP ranges as callback URLs with the identity provider, how would one get around this issue?

Comment: Ah - looks like I misunderstood. Maybe the device flow would work - which tends to involve users providing credentials via mobile apps when there is no browser redirect capability: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/02/19/add-oauth-device-flow-to-any-server

Comment: Technically device flow may be the right option - but a bigger question is whether it will be acceptable for your end users. Sometimes OAuth standards don't provide a perfect solution and trade offs are needed - such as bespoke solutions.